# What to use to design a piece of wearable fitness garment?

Tags: 3d, drawing, cad, design, clothing

[https://www.amazon.com/Everlast-6010G-Weighted-Vest-Reflective/dp/B008RI0GD8/ref=sr_1_11?crid=3VJ3HC3QI1XKQ&keywords=weighted+vest&qid=1641836008&sprefix=weighted+vest%2Caps%2C205&sr=8-11](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008RI0GD8)

The above is what I have in mind. Basically a piece of cloth filled with sand. What software is sued to design such?

OS:

Linux Mint
It simply nees to be able to produce a 3D model of the design.

Comment: On which OS, at what price? What features do you need, what should it be capable of? One might be tempted to recommend you some simple drawing program for the Palm Pilot, which would almost match the criteria you've given ;) Can you please **[edit]** your question and provide the missing details? Thanks!

Comment: edited. the OS in linux mint.

Comment: Thanks! No the other missing pieces, please ;)

Comment: edited. just need to be able to create a 3D model.

Comment: OK, thanks then and good luck! Hope the price doesn't get too high then :D

Comment: [Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)?